# Flex buttons with scrollview React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I have searched high and low to try and find an answer for this problem that I'm having. Basically, I have a scrollview with lots of items that are checkboxes. I want to have a few buttons on the bottom that are 'select all' 'select none' type actions. I want the buttons to equally take up the available space (e.g. stretch so that there are no gaps). I've tried a ton of different combinations of styles for the buttons and the containers with no luck.

I have a working example here, but I'll post the code as well for convenience. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** As suggested, I've looked at `ButtonGroup` from `react-native-elements` but I didn't like how the buttons stayed selected. Plus, I feel like this is a common issue that I've yet to find a solution to with flexbox in react native.

[image]

https://snack.expo.io/BJNEmvMvQ

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox, ListItem, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends Component {
  list = [ list of objects to render checkboxes (see snack for example  ];

  renderItem = (item, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={i}>
        <CheckBox
          title={item.Description}
          checkedIcon="check"
          uncheckedIcon="times"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>{this.list.map(this.renderItem)}</ScrollView>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        // have tried in the view style above: flexGrow, alignItems, and others
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'black'}}
            // have tried using flexGrow, alignSelf  
            // have also tried using 'buttonStyle' here instead of 'containerViewStyle'
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'black' }}
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'black' }}
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'black' }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty giving each button style with {flex: 1}

Comment: @yedidyak Yeah I thought about that and tried it, it doesn't change anything on the buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with some help from the folks at `react-native-elements`. I needed to remove the margin from the buttons that are there as default on the `containerViewStyle` and add a `flex: 1` as well. Updated snack is [here](https://snack.expo.io/SJJFkGQwQ). It is essentially the same as one of the other answers except you don't have to wrap the buttons in views, just apply the styles to the `containerViewStyle` for each of the buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox, ListItem, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends Component {
  list = [ list of objects to render checkboxes (see snack for example  ];

  renderItem = (item, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={i}>
        <CheckBox
          title={item.Description}
          checkedIcon="check"
          uncheckedIcon="times"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView>{this.list.map(this.renderItem)}</ScrollView>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, flex: 1 }}
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, flex: 1 }}
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, flex: 1 }}
          />
          <Button
            title="hello"
            containerViewStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'black', marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, flex: 1 }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are limitations to change react native button styles. The quick solution for your problem is to wrap the Button with View.

Here is the working demo: https://snack.expo.io/SkIXThMw7

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView>{this.list.map(this.renderItem)}</ScrollView>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style={{flex:1}} >
                    <Button
                        title="hello"
                        containerViewStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                    >
                    </Button>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}} >
                    <Button
                        title="hello"
                        containerViewStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                    >
                    </Button>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}} >
                    <Button
                        title="hello"
                        containerViewStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                    >
                    </Button>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1}} >
                    <Button
                        title="hello"
                        containerViewStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                    >
                    </Button>
                </View>
            </View>
    </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonStyle: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'black',
      marginLeft: 0,
      marginRight: 0,
      paddingLeft: 0,
      paddingRight: 0
   },

});
```

Comment: That's definitely the look that I'm looking for. You said this is the quick solution, is there a not quick solution that doesn't use the views?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be useful try to use ButtonGroup which is a part of react-native-elements and make the below changes given in the snack example to your render function:

Reference for the above solution is https://snack.expo.io/Hkdg7OGv7 given here please check.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but I didn't like how the buttons stay selected with ButtonGroup. I wanted them to be more independent.